# PIL.Image class not found with Pillow

Tags: windows, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I just installed Pillow (the PIL fork) with `pip3` on Windows and I can import it, but the `Image` class cannot be found :

```
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in [Pillow's documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) :

> Warning
>
> Pillow >= 1.0 no longer supports “import Image”. Please use
>   “from PIL import Image” instead.

`from PIL import Image` worked.